# How to add a gif in ImageView?

Tags: android

I have stuck on adding gif into ImageView.
I understand use WebView can easily display the gif repeatedly, but is there any way to add gif in ImageView?
I tried to convert WebView to ImageView use following codes:

```
    image = new ImageView(context);
    view = new GifWebView(context, "file:///android_asset/move.gif");
    Bitmap bmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c= new Canvas(bmap);
    view.draw(c);

    image.setMaxHeight(500);
    image.setMaxWidth(500);
    image.setImageBitmap(bmap);
    image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

but when I run it, there just a white 500*500 space.

Comment: Can you explain, why you need that?

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class Gifview extends View {

    private InputStream gifInputStream;
     private Movie gifMovie;
     private int movieWidth, movieHeight;
     private long movieDuration;
     private long mMovieStart;

     public Gifview(Context context) {
      super(context);
      init(context);
     }

     public Gifview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
      init(context);
     }

     public Gifview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, 
       int defStyleAttr) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
      init(context);
     }

     private void init(Context context){
      setFocusable(true);
      gifInputStream = context.getResources()
        .openRawResource(R.drawable.skiing);

      gifMovie = Movie.decodeStream(gifInputStream);
      movieWidth = gifMovie.width();
      movieHeight = gifMovie.height();
      movieDuration = gifMovie.duration();
     }

     @Override
     protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, 
       int heightMeasureSpec) {
      setMeasuredDimension(movieWidth, movieHeight);
     }

     public int getMovieWidth(){
      return movieWidth;
     }

     public int getMovieHeight(){
      return movieHeight;
     }

     public long getMovieDuration(){
      return movieDuration;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

      long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            if (mMovieStart == 0) {   // first time
                mMovieStart = now;
            }

            if (gifMovie != null) {

                int dur = gifMovie.duration();
                if (dur == 0) {
                    dur = 1000;
                }

                int relTime = (int)((now - mMovieStart) % dur);

                gifMovie.setTime(relTime);

                gifMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
                invalidate();

            }

     }

}
```

Use this view. And place your gif image instead of skiing.

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.playgif.MainActivity" >

    <com.example.playgif.Gifview
        android:id="@+id/gifview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```